# UIWebView's "loadHTMlString" is showing blank screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, asihttprequest

How to render the following html in UIwebview using loadHTMLString. 
The webview is showing blank screen.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="1,*" frameborder=0 framespacing=0 cols="*">
    <frame src="blank.html" 
      marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
      scrolling="no noresize">
    <frame src="index1.html" 
      marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
      scrolling="yes noresize">
    <noframes></noframes>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: try synchronous request.

Comment: tried that too
[request startSynchronous];